# Twig UTF8 Character Encoding - Symfony2

Tags: html, utf-8, twig

I am developing a news system for a french association's website with Symfony2. I'm having troubles when it comes to displaying the accents and also HTML.

In the twig view I simply output the variable:

```
{{ article.body }}
```

If I insert the accent directly in the database like this: 'é', the variable is not even displayed.

If I insert this instead: `&eacute;` it stays the same.

HTML is shown as text.

I also tried the `autoescape` function (set to `true` and `false`), no success :

```
{% autoescape true %}
    {{ article.body }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try writing "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />" in the head of your template?

Comment: Yes i did. When i type characters directly in the view everything works fine. I also made sure that the database was encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: article.body comes from the database, right? can you confirm that the accented text is stored correctly in the database?

Answer (score 13):

First you need setting the charset in your HTML code

```
<!-- for HTML5 -->
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Second "convert_encoding()"  is a twig function which convert variable to other encoding.

```
{{ article.body | convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') }}
```

But maybe, you need to use raw before convert your variable

```
{{ article.body | raw | convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') }}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/convert_encoding.html

Comment: This simple solution made my day.

Answer (score 3):

Encoding problem could appear in the next places:

1. The HTML document:

   ```
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   ```
2. The files you use (controllers and views normally).
3. The database connection. The charset parameter must be set to 'utf8'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the twig files and controllers into UTF-8!
The similar problem was here (when passing variables from the controller to twig), and this solved the problem.

Comment: your "here" and "this" links are missing

Comment: I'm guessing this is a case of bad translation.  I am reading this as "I had a similar problem in this same spot", "this" then makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you have in the ddbb something like this

```
&aacute;rbol

{% autoescape %}
  {{ c.data|raw }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

This will show

```
árbol
```